# gcnew and secure erasure

Tags: security, c++-cli, erasure

I have memory that I have to allocate with gcnew (C++, passing the memory to managed code), which will contain secure information (passwords, HIPAA data, etc.).  I realize that such memory is garbage collected, and that implies that I don't control when it is deallocated.  But that wouldn't be a problem if there was a way to guarantee it got securely wiped before I turn loose of it.

Is there a way to guarantee gcnew'd memory is securely erased?  In my particular case, I'm gcnew'ing String objects, but a general approach would be even better.

Comment: Please mind memory compaction by your implementations moving managed gc too.

Comment: It is not the de-allocation that's the problem, it the heap compaction.  Which can leave long-living copies of the data behind.  Only slightly exacerbated by immutable objects like System::String, which already has a workaround.  There is no good substitute for physical security.  A locked door.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an elegant solution to the problem. But, this should be a non-issue/concern if the system running your code is properly secured in accordance to HIPPA.

You may also want to try SecureString instead of String:

[SecureString: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

[CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549109/Working-with-SecureString)